# Replacing values in a dataset

Tags: replacement, dataset, query, missing

Could someone explain why

```
{<|"Price" -> 1, "Brand" -> "A"|>, 
 <|"Color" -> "b", "Brand" -> "A"|>} //
Dataset[#][All, {"Price" -> 2}] &
```

fails instead of returning a dataset with

```
{<|"Price" -> 2, "Brand" -> "A"|>, 
 <|"Color" -> "b", "Brand" -> "A"|>}
```

?
It seems that we cannot change a value unless the relative key is defined on all the rows of the dataset.

Mathematica 11.3 on Debian 9 here. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Look at the `DisplayForm` of the dataset first, it's not what you think.

Here's one way to do it:

```
d={<|"Price" -> 1, "Brand" -> "A"|>, 
 <|"Color" -> "b", "Brand" -> "A"|>} //
Dataset[KeyUnion@#]&; 
d[All,{"Price"->(If[!MissingQ@#,2,#]&)}]
```

Comment: `KeyUnion` is key :) Thanks